# Solr query to return results ordered by 'find in set'

Tags: solr, solr4

Here is the problem.

I have a solr query like this:

Example:

```
post_id: ( 31234, 56756, 24352, 78465, 23424 )
```

And i want to order them , as they are in the query.

Mysql equivalent to this is:

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(post_id, '31234, 56756, 24352, 78465, 23424')
```

I was looking on the Solr sort documentation, googling etc. but nothing.
Is it possible to order articles in Solr like this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have that kind of Order if you boost your documents accordingly.

for e.g. `q=post_id:31234^5 post_id:56756^4 post_id:24352^3` .....

Comment: Awesome! 1024 10x 4d F1 ( thanks alot for the help ). You saved my day!

Comment: I'd just like to call attention that I could only make this work safely by using huge boost factors like ^10000 ^1000 ^100 ^10 and so on as suggested in their wiki.. but then, you will end up with length issues if you have a lot of IDs to search